# why hardcoded text in array() works but same text as var doesnt: array($var)

Tags: php

sometimes trying to figure out the right question is the hardest part.

i want to run a query that checks for several possibilities that might occur in a column of data

this code works like i want it:

```
$states = array('CA','CO','TX');
$states_str = implode("','",$states);

$query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state IN ('$states_str')";
```

but the problem is the array variables are hardwired

i want the user to select the states (in this case) they want, gather them up inside a variable, and then place that variable inside the array () to get the same result

ie

```
$var = ('CA','CO','TX')
$states = array($var);
$states_str = implode("','",$states);

$query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state IN ('$states_str')";
```

but for some reason that wont work even though the string is exactly the same.

Comment: _“but for some reason that wont work even though the string is exactly the same”_ – but the _context_ is different. In the first code, it is the language _parser_ that sees that _code_ and recognizes it as the syntax for an array, whereas in the second code you are beyond the level of parsing and at run-time already, and there a string value is just a string value.

Comment: that would explain why it is not working, thanks, now how do i get he contents of $var to work with $query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state IN ('$states_str')"; ... the purpose is to run a single query and check for multiple possible values chosen by the user within a single column of a mysql db. that is the question. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$var` is already an array, so wrapping it around another `array()` makes it a multi-dim array, eg

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
      [0] => 'CA',
      [1] => 'CO',
      [2] => 'TX'
    )
```

IOW don't wrap the values in an array since it's already an array. Or else, if you keep it the way you have it, use `implode("','",$states[0]);`